# jump to anchor on html page from google map marker api v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know how to jump to an anchor on the html page that holds a google map by clicking on a marker in the map.

tried this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#'+i+'').position().top);
    // open new infowindow
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

This isn't working..
Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very belated answer as I came across this today while trying to do the same thing:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  window.location = "#anchor";
});
```